# GPO WMI username filter not working over RDP

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, group-policy, sql, wmi

I'm trying to write a WMI filter to prevent a GPO from applying to certain users

```
SELECT * from Win32_ComputerSystem WHERE NOT UserName LIKE 'domain\\user1_%' AND NOT UserName LIKE 'domain\\user2_%'
```

This works correctly if the user is logged onto the console but always returns false if the user is logged on via RDP.

Mark

EDIT:

There does seem to be a way to achieve this, it's described in method two of [this](http://learn-powershell.net/2010/11/01/quick-hit-find-currently-logged-on-users/) article. Though, I am unsure of how to construct the query using Win32_Process?

Comment: Is the user logging into the same computer in both cases?

Comment: Under normal circumstances, yes. But it must work universally.

Comment: Is there anyone out there that could possibly shed some light on this issue?

Comment: Try running gpresults against the computer and user when the user is logged on via RDP to see if anything stands out.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use a WMI filter for that.  Use an Access Control Entry for "Apply Group Policy" permission on the GPO object to specify a group for which the GPO should be applied/denied.  You would also need to ensure that loopback policy processing is enabled.

Comment: Greg, I'm trying to avoid the use of Active Directory security groups and GPO security filtering/delegation. As you can see the WMI filter above uses wildcards - it will potentially be filtering out hundreds of different user accounts. Maintaining those users within their respective security groups would be a nightmare.

Comment: If the users do in fact have a consistent naming schemes, a scheduled task that ensures that accounts with these username patterns are in the appropriate groups is actually fairly trivial.  Arguably, adjusting a filter in a PowerShell script (or equivalent) is easier to achieve -- and easier to troubleshoot -- than a WMI filter in a GPO.